# Render Text in an Image with Uneven Level of Saturation

Tags: python, image, image-processing, noise, distortion

How to I render my text with uneven level of saturation, just like the second image? (The font of the two image is different but saturation level is of concern.)

[image]

[image]

My initial code is

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

from random import seed
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import os.path

#Returns the text size in terms of width and height.
def getSize(txt, font):
    testImg = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1))
    testDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(testImg)
    return testDraw.textsize(txt, font)

text = 'lemper'
fontname = 'arial.ttf'
fontsize= 25

font = ImageFont.truetype(fontname, fontsize)
width, height = getSize(text, font)

#Creates an image with white background of constant size.
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), 'white')
d = ImageDraw.Draw( img)
d.text(get_xy_coordinates(text, font), text, fill='black', font=font)             
img.save("text_images/1.png")
```

Comment: would you just like to change the saturation or along with font and other, as both images are not matching ?

Comment: @NagaKiranThe font of the two image is different but saturation level is of concern.

Comment: Saturation is the vividness of a colour and black (as well as white and grey-shades) are by definition fully unsaturated, i.e. have no saturation. So I think that is maybe the wrong word. You could print your text in dark grey instead of black. You could print your text with partial opacity so some of the uneven background shows through.

Comment: Please reach me, if you need Customized OCR Engine

Answer (score 1):

I hope saturation wont bring any change as it is a binary image, i think you are looking for adding some noise to image.

Please have a look at [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) library, add or remove the relevant image processing techniques based on your need

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa


a = cv2.imread('fontimage.jpg')[None,:,:,:]
# Standard scenario: You have N RGB-images and additionally 21 heatmaps per

images = a.copy()
heatmaps = np.random.random(size=(1, 64, 64, 1)).astype(np.float32)

seq = iaa.Sequential([
    # Comment or uncomment the filters on your preference
    #iaa.GaussianBlur((0,3.0)),
    iaa.MultiplyHueAndSaturation((0.5, 1.5), per_channel=True),
    iaa.MultiplySaturation((0.1, 0.4)),
    iaa.SaltAndPepper(0.2)
])

images_aug, heatmaps_aug = seq(images=images, heatmaps=heatmaps)
```

Out:

[image: Converted Image]